# My SwiftUI Code results in a big ol blank window

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

So I've been working on an app to recreate the iOS battery widget on Mac but all of my efforts have resulted in a blank screen. Here is my code, any help is appreciated.

I've tried all manner of different approaches including the `LazyVGrid` to no avail.

Thanks so much for even taking a look and I hope you have a nice day!

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var devices: [Device] = [
    Device(name: "Mark's Mac Book pro", type: .macbook, level: 1.00),
    Device(name: "MX Master 2S", type: .mouse, level: 0.75),
    Device(name: "MX Keys", type: .keyboard, level: 0.50),
    Device(name: "Mark's Airpods Max", type: .airpodsMax, level: 0.63)
]
@State var size: Double = 150.00

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        BatteryGrid(devices: $devices, size: $size)
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 300, minHeight: 175)
}
}
```

BatterGrid.swift

```
struct BatteryGrid: View {

@Binding var devices: [Device]
@Binding var size: Double
@State var count = 0
@ObservedObject var deviceArrays = PublishedDevices()
@State var devicesPerRow = 0
@State var rows = 0
@State var currentDevice = Device()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ForEach(deviceArrays.devices, id: \.id) { deviceArray in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(deviceArray.row, id: \.id) { device in
                        Progresso(device: $currentDevice, size: $size)
                            .onAppear {
                                setCurrentDevice(to: device)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                devicesPerRow = Int(geometry.size.width.rounded(.up)) / Int(size.rounded(.down))
                rows = devices.count / devicesPerRow
            }
        }
    }
}

func setCurrentDevice(to device: Device) {
    currentDevice = device
}

}

struct DeviceRow: Identifiable {
var row: [Device] = []
var id = UUID()
}
class PublishedDevices: ObservableObject {
@Published var devices: [DeviceRow] = []
}
```

and finally Progresso.swift

```
struct Progresso: View {
@Binding var device: Device
@Binding var size: Double
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Circle()
            .stroke(lineWidth: 8)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .opacity(0.30)
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.0, to: device.level ?? 0)
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 8, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 100)
            .foregroundColor((device.level ?? 0) > 0.20 ? .green : .red)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
        VStack {
            device.icon()
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            Text("\(Int(((device.level ?? 0) * 100).rounded(.up)))%")
                .font(.body.bold())
                .frame(width: 75)
                .lineLimit(1)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is `PublishedDevices` doing? And why do you declare `@Binding`s but don't use the two-way-binding at all?

Comment: @vadian, I used the `PublishedDevices` class in a vain attempt to get my code to update in the ForEcah loop. Should I use environment variables instead of the bindings? Thanks! (P.S. I'm relatively new to all of this haha)

Comment: You need `@Binding` only if you want to modify the value in the child view and inform the parent. If not just use regular `let` constants. Your `BatteryGrid` view relies on the devices in `PublishedDevices`. If the class doesn't publish anything the screen remains blank.

Answer (score 0):

The view is blank because you iterate through an empty array `deviceArrays.devices` as it described here

```
class PublishedDevices: ObservableObject {
@Published var devices: [DeviceRow] = []
}
```

Also, in your `BatteryGrid` struct when you declare `PublishedDevices` as an `@ObservedObject`. It acts as a Source Of Truth for your view, so you must declare it as a `@StateObject`

`@ObservedObject` is used when you pass a Source of Truth (View Model) to another view

More info on State Object is here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject